# How to set product urls to no-index no-follow?

Tags: magento-1.9, seo, canonical

How we can set the list of products urls to **no-index no-follow** those products are canonical

Answer (score 1):

Go to the your_theme/template/page/html/head.phtml

add a condition

```
<?php
if(Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction()->getFullActionName()=='catalog_product_view') {
    $_product = Mage::registry('current_product');
    if($_product->getCanonical()){
        ?>
        <meta name="robots" content="NOINDEX,FOLLOW" />
        <?php
    }
}
?>
```

Where `$_product->getCanonical()` would be the attribute that you should assign to the products where no index nofollow required

Comment: Actually i have a csv in which a list of urls given these urls are of  product with category or without category in between,in short we need to no index no follow the urls that are here.how is this possible?

Comment: I would recommend to create a custom database table and a cutom model for your list of urls and implement the suggested approach from Shoaib checking against that model

Comment: create a new attribute **canonial** with **"Yes/No"** values, its default value should be **"No"**. Now from your csv, assign **"Yes"** to all the products. Then use my code, it will work

Comment: Note: Your CSV should contain sku so that it would update through profiler